# Why is Stellar on HTTP and not HTTPS?

Tags: security, horizon

On the Stellar website: "API: Horizon Most applications interact with the Stellar network through Horizon, a RESTful HTTP API server. Horizon gives you a straightforward way to submit transactions, check accounts, and subscribe to events. Because it’s just HTTP, you can communicate with Horizon using your web browser, simple command line tools like cURL, or the Stellar SDK for your favorite programming language."

So why HTTP and not HTTPS? Isn't HTTPS a standard today?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you can see [from the developer documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/index.html), SDF *does* serve both Horizon instances through HTTPS.

When they say "RESTful HTTP API" it's to signal to developers that they use [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web technologies.